# Skip a specified number of columns with numpy.genfromtxt()

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large table (numbers in text format) that I would like to load with `numpy.genfromtxt()`. I would like to ignore the first *n* columns, say 5. I do not know the size of the table (number of row or columns) in advance.

I saw that `genfromtxt()` has an option `skip_header` that allows to skip a specified number of header rows, but it seems there is no such option for columns. There is a `usecols` option but there I must specify the column numbers I want to keep, rather than those I want to discard (I do not know this number in advance).

Obviously I could just load the whole thing and then throw away the first *n* columns, but this is not elegant and is wasteful in terms of memory.

Also I could peak into the file, find the number of columns, and then construct the `usecols` argument, but that is rather messy.

Any ideas on how to solve this elegantly? Is there some hidden/undocumented argument that I can use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In newer versions of Numpy, `np.genfromtxt` can take an iterable argument, so you can wrap the file you're reading in a generator that generates lines, skipping the first `N` columns. If your numbers are space-separated, that's something like

```
np.genfromtxt(" ".join(ln.split()[N:]) for ln in f)
```

Comment: what is wrong? firstImage = np.genfromtxt (" ".join(ln.split()[1:]) for ln in path+next(iter(filelist)))

Answer (score 22):

For older versions of numpy, peeking at the first line to discover the number of columns is not that hard:

```
import numpy as np
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    num_cols = len(f.readline().split())
    f.seek(0)
    data = np.genfromtxt(f, usecols = range(5,num_cols))
print(data)
```