# Skip a specified number of columns with numpy.genfromtxt() python 3.4 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, genfromtxt

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Open a file
path = "input/"

filelist = list(filter(lambda s: s.endswith(".asc"), os.listdir(path)))
firstImage = np.genfromtxt (" ".join(ln.split()[1:]) for ln in path+next(iter(filelist)))
```

what is wrong? getting: TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: What are you trying to do to the file name? Seems pretty unclear to me.. iterating over a string yield the letters. Can you write what `" ".join(ln.split()[1:]) for ln in path+next(iter(filelist))` yields to you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311471/skip-a-specified-number-of-columns-with-numpy-genfromtxt my question is looks same but I cant go without errors. I need to remove first column to able shape in array : imageArray = np.zeros((len(filelist),) + firstImage.shape)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the function's doc, it seems able to to all kinds of crazy things out of the box :

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Including but not limited to, using the `usecols` parameters would allow you to skip using some columns.

Then there would be no need for fancy operations